# How to Load CSV file in React Native

Tags: json, csv, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to download one `CSV` file in my React Native Project. I have put `CSV` file in assets folder in `React Native Project`, I'm using `RNFS` for fetching the same.

But when I `console log` `RNFS.MainBundlePath` it returns `undefined value`. Below is my Code to get the path from `RNFS`.

```
var mainBundlePath = RNFS.MainBundlePath;
var path = '/assets/Product.csv';
```

Any suggestions on this matter?

Answer (score 0):

There you can user below library it will help me to achieve same thing in past.

Try [csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson)

**you can Installation**

`npm i --save csvtojson`

see the example given [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson#library)

Comment: It is giving me this Error:  Cannot find module 'fs'

Comment: Hardik, I have placed my CSV file in assets folder. And I want to access that.

Comment: u can't access directly
u need to parse it

Comment: I know I have to parse it but right now I'm not able to access it. I'm using  RNFS.readFileAssets to access the file. I have put csv file on this path '/app/src/main/assets' in Android. Do you have any idea how to access it?

Comment: u can import file using `require`